# Api-platform: corsAllowOrigin doesn't set *

Tags: api-platform.com

Oke so back to https://api-platform.com :)

So I currently have `corsAllowOrigin: "*" #to allow all origins` in my helm values file (as per docs). To make sure that the propper headers are bieng set on return values.

Now I would expect (as per [docs](https://api-platform.com/docs/admin/getting-started/)) that the Access-Control-Allow-Origin: would now go to "*" however it goes to `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null`. That's of course a bit annoying because it prevent react native apps of accessing the API.

Question here, is this a bug? Am I using the wrong values? Or overlooking something?

Answer (score 5):

Sets .env file with:

```
###> nelmio/cors-bundle ###
CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=['*']
###< nelmio/cors-bundle ###
```

Answer (score 3):

By default, API Platform uses nelmio cors and the default config use the environment variable **CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN**.

With that you can allow any url with this config in your .env (or .env.local) with `CORS_ALLOW_ORIGIN=^https?://.*?$`

Comment: Is still the case?

Answer (score 0):

As the others have said, CORS is handled by `nelmio/cors-bundle`. If you don't wish to modify env files, the actual package configuration for it is documented on its GitHub page https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioCorsBundle.

The configuration you'd want to modify is the `allow_origin` configuration, which can have a default value or can be configured based on the path of the current request. Pretty neat.

In `config/packages/nelmio_cors.yaml`:

```
nelmio_cors:
        defaults:
            ...
            allow_origin: []
            ...
        paths:
            '^/api/':
                ...
                allow_origin: ['*']
                ...
            '^/':
                ...
                allow_origin: ['^http://localhost:[0-9]+']
                ...
```

Comment: Order in "paths" maters.  '^/api/' will be ignored of set after '^/'